# How to compute this integral not using complex analysis?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ln(\mathrm{e}^{2x}+1)\mathrm{d}x$$

I am trying to solve it not using complex analysis but I did not figure it out. Can this integral be resolved not using complex analysis?

Edit: Sorry for lack of background. I'm a student major in literature but kinda interested in mathematics. The background of this integral is that I came across the concept of [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) of continuous random variables. In this meantime, I am studying a reinforcement learning algorithm - Soft Actor Critic (SAC), where the authors model a continuous variable but use Monte Carlo method to calculate the entropy. I know it holds in the approximation sense, but I still wonder if I can accurately compute the integral (entropy).

The original problem is: what is the differential entropy of $a=\tanh(u)$ where $u\sim\mathcal{N}(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$.
My steps are as follows:

1. The probability density of $a$ is denoted by $\pi(a)$ and can be computed readily:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \pi(a)&=p(u)\left\vert\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\mathrm{d}u}\right\vert^{-1}~(a=\text{tanh}(u))\\
    &=p(u)\frac{1}{1-\text{tanh}^2(u)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$

2. Then the differential entropy can be expanded as:
   \begin{equation}
       \begin{aligned}
           \mathcal{H}&=-\int_{-1}^{1}\pi(a)\log\pi(a)\mathrm{d}a\\
           &=-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(u)\log\left(\frac{p(u)}{1-\text{tanh}^2(u)}\right)\mathrm{d}u\\
           &=\underbrace{-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(u)\log p(u)\mathrm{d}u}_{A}\\
           &+\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(u)\log\left(1-\text{tanh}^2(u)\right)\mathrm{d}u}_{B}
       \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}
3. $A=\ln(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi\mathrm{e}})$ is trivial. Expanding $B$:
   \begin{equation}
       \begin{aligned}
       B&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x)\log\left(1-\text{tanh}^2(x)\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
       &=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\cdot 2\ln\frac{2\mathrm{e}^x}{\mathrm{e}^{2x}+1}\mathrm{d}x\\
       &=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
       &~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\left(\ln 2+x-\ln(\mathrm{e}^{2x}+1)\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
       &=B_1+B_2-B_3
       \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}

Now term $B_3$ is exactly this problem. I tried different approaches, such as integral by parts, substituting with trigonometric functions but none of them works. As I did not learn complex analysis, I want to know if it can be done not using complex analysis.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4666784/edit) the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does not seem convergent. Perhaps you missed the minus sign in the exponent.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Oh yes, sorry for the typo. I also edit this problem and add some background.